# Inserir multipos valores em componente

Tags: javascript, jquery

bem galera, estou enfrentando o seguinte problema:

tenho que setar vários valores em um  que está usando o plugin abaixo.

para setar apenas um valor estou usando a seguinte sintaxe

```
$("#s").select2('val',1);
```

agora como posso fazer para inserir mais de um valor?

[select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Comment: Pode verificar nos exemplos.: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data

Comment: Então cara, eu já estou me baseando pela doc, dei uma sacada e não obtive sucesso @Tiago Gomes

Comment: Na pergunta não tem essa informação, sugiro que informe o que tentou e qual o erro que surgiu. Colocar um exemplo no jsfiddle tambem ajuda na analise do constragimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem algum dia precisar implementei o seguinte código e consegui obter o resultado que queria..

```
var values = "1,2,3"

$.each(values.split(","),function(i,e){
   $("#select option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});

$("#select").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo, usando uma váriavel `data` com os valores do select, e se você estar querendo selecionar mais de um item por vez no dropdown e só adicionar o atributo `multiple="multiple"` no seu select:

HTML:

```
<select id="s" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var data = [
  { id: 0, text: 'enhancement', selected: true},
  { id: 1, text: 'bug' },
  { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' },
  { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, 
  { id: 4, text: 'wontfix', selected: true}
];

$("#s").select2({
  data: data
});
```

Onde nesse objeto Json o **id's** representam os values dos options do select, e o **text's** os textos a serem exibidos.

Link para [teste](https://jsfiddle.net/yrc6fete/).

Comment: então @Yure Pereira, esta solução que me deu já tinha até tentando, mas não obtive sucesso.
Preciso de algo dessa maneira https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

Comment: Preciso que esse <select> apareça com os valores que eu setar no js

Comment: Dessa maneira: https://jsfiddle.net/YurePereira/69p84xyo/

Comment: Você está querendo selecionar mais de um item por vez?

Comment: Se for isso, é só adicionar o atributo multiple="multiple" no select.

Comment: não não @Yure Pereira, quero poder do js setar um valor e no meu html aparecer esses valores já selecionados..

Comment: Utiliza "selected: true" nos itens que você quer deixar selecionados, como no exemplo.

Comment: Fala ae @Yure Pereira, tentei utilizar essa regra mas não deu certo. segue o codigo que implementei
 `$("#select option[value=" + 3 + "]").prop("selected", true);`